# Python internals

Tags: python

Can anyone please direct me to an online document or books where I can  find and learn about the Python implementation in C, like this one for Perl: http://perldoc.perl.org/index-internals.html
or this book: *Extending and Embedding Perl by Simon Cozen*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure you tried Googling or looking on docs.python.org before asking this question?

This is the "official" tutorial on extending the interpreter which should be a start - http://docs.python.org/extending/index.html and then there is the [C API reference](http://docs.python.org/c-api/index.html) which should be useful while you're doing your work.

[Eli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8206/eli-bendersky) has an ongoing series of posts describing the innards of the interpreter on [his blog](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/category/programming/python/python-internals/).

Comment: Thanks Noufal for the pointers. Sorry I should have searched around before asking.The reference to Eli's site is particularly appreciated,. Cheers!